# DMA Scatter-Gather and contiguous memory?

Tags: linux-device-driver, dma

I understand that the use of scatter-gather in DMA is to scatter - gather data from small memory segments because large contiguous blocks of memory are not easy to find. So If I need to to do S-G should I allocate small pieces of memory using kmalloc? What is the max size I can alloc at one go for one descriptor ?
Is there any other use of S-G feature?

Comment: *"If I need to to do S-G should I allocate small pieces of memory"* -- That seems backwards.  You don't choose to do scatter/gather, and then intentionally allocate small chunks of memory.  You use it because it's available or you have to (e.g. to save on copying overhead).  For a multi-sector disk transfer, each segment in the s/g list could be 512 bytes.  The max segment size is typically the same as the maximum DMA transfer size.

Comment: Correction:  The segment size in POSIX and Linux systems must be larger than zero, and less than or equal to `IOV_MAX`, which is defined in `<limits.h>`. In Linux, `IOV_MAX` or `UIO_MAXIOV` is currently 1024.

Comment: @kartik is your question for memory to device or the device to memory?